# sufficient and necessary condition for Normality of a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Question is to :

Prove that a subgroup $N$ of a group $G$ is Normal iff $gNg^{-1}\subseteq N$ for all $g\in G$.

But, we define $N\unlhd G$ if $gN=Ng$ i.e., $gNg^{-1}=N$.

So, question should be some thing like  :

Prove that a subgroup $N$ of a group $G$ is Normal iff $gNg^{-1}= N$ for all $g\in G$.

which is obvious. So, I see that I have not understood the question properly.

Please let me know what exactly does the question imply??

after writing this question it was written in brackets that :

For an arbitrary subgroup $N$ the set 
$\{g\in G : gNg^{-1}\subseteq N\}$ need not be closed under inverses. So, do not try to prove the more general statement that this set equals the normalizer of $G$.

I see that $gNg^{-1}\subseteq N$ does not necessarily imply in general that $g^{-1}N(g^{-1})^{-1}\subseteq N$ i.e., $g^{-1}Ng\subseteq N$. (unless the set $N$ is finite)

So, the set $\{g\in G : gNg^{-1}\subseteq N\}$ is not closed under inverse.

But, what does this have anything to do withe original question :O

Please let me know what does the question exactly mean??

P.S : I did not understand the question properly, so, i am not sure i have even written the question properly. So,If some one do not find the question clearly, please see for the question $3.1.25$ in the book Abstrct Algebra -Dummit foote $2^{nd}$ edition.

Comment: I think what is meant by $gNg^{-1}\subset N$ is that N is closed under conjugation by G.

Comment: The question means exactly what it says: "prove that a subgroup $N$ of a group $G$ is normal in $G$ if and only if $gNg^{-1} \subseteq N$ for all $g \in G$". Just try and answer it.

Comment: no.no. I feel he wants me to see that "N" need not be finite.. if $N$ is finite, it is obvious that "iff $gNg^{-1}\subseteq N$ for all $g\in G$."

Comment: Why do you write "no.no."? The question means exactly what it says - nothing more, nothing less! It says nothing about $N$ being finite.

Comment: I understood that now! Sorry for the lame reply...

Answer (score 1):

**Definition** A subgroup $N\subseteq G$ is **normal** in $G$ if $g^{-1}Ng=N$ for all $g\in G$.

**Lemma 1** A subgroup $N\subseteq G$ is normal in $G$ iff $gN=Ng$ for all $g\in G$.

Note that **Lemma 1** is just a reformulation of the definition. **Lemma 2** below furnishes another (perhaps, less obvious) reformulation of the definition.

**Lemma 2** A subgroup $N\subseteq G$ is normal in $G$ iff $g^{-1}Ng\subseteq N$ for all $g\in G$.

*Proof* Let $g\in G$ and let $h=g^{-1}\in G$. By hypothesis, $g^{-1}Ng\subseteq N$ and $h^{-1}Nh\subseteq N$. The latter is equivalent to $gNg^{-1}\subseteq N$ which, in turn, is equivalent to $N\subseteq g^{-1}Ng$. Therefore, $g^{-1}Ng=N$ and since $g\in G$ was arbitrary, the proof is complete. **Q.E.D.**

Does that answer your question?

Comment: no.no. I feel he wants me to see that "N" need not be finite.. if $N$ is finite, it is obvious that "iff $gNg^{-1}\subseteq N$ for all $g\in G$."

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik My answer doesn't assume finiteness of $N$ at any stage so I'm not sure I understand your comment.

Comment: Ok, I got it now :)